# How to create a view for nested comments?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to have a nested comment system for my project. I have product model so I want to clients can comment on my products. I have my product and comment models and serializers and I related comments to products in product serializer so I can show product comments. what should i do to clients can write their comment for products??? the comments must be nested. this is my code:

#models

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True, related_name='replys')
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} - {self.body[:30]}'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
```

#serializers:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'product', 'parent', 'body', 'created']


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'category', 'name', 'slug', 'image_1',
                  'image_2', 'image_3', 'image_4', 'image_5',
                  'description', 'price', 'available', 'created', 'updated', 'comments']
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }
```

how should be my view??

#views:

```
class Home(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['name', 'category__name', 'description']



class RetrieveProductView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) ? Otherwise your code seems correct since you have already set `related_name='comments'`. One thing I can think of is you added `related_name` after and you forgot to run `python manage.py makemigrations`

```py
class RetrieveProductView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.prefetch_related('comments').all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

Comment: I need a view for writing comments. clients can add comment

Comment: oh ok that wasn't very clear... I understood you weren't able to list the comments within a product. have a look at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save , you can do that in `perform_create` of `CreateAPIView`. you should end up doing something like `serializer.save(user=self.request.user, product=instance)`. you need to perform a request to grab an instance of your product `instance = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')` assuming you build a URL with your product slug.

Comment: please look at my last question I wrote the view but I have error can you tell me how to fix it???

Comment: In the end of the code i must add a line what should i write??

Comment: I wrote the comment view could you please check it. is it true??